# Replace Nested loops with more efficient algorthm

Tags: python, algorithm, nested

I am working a problem where I need to identify an object in an 600x600 image (after masking), by finding a line along the image which maximizes the number of elements in the matrix.

My code right now has 4 nested loops to achieve this. It is quite inefficient as you can see, wondering if anyone knows how to do this better?

In essense, the code should try several possible lines within the image, extract the elements from the image along the line, and use a summation. Once iterations finish the line with the maximum number of elements will be identified.

Hence this issue is not simply how to replace the nested loops, I need something that will try a large number of line combinations with various m and c in: y = mx + c.

I did also try only iterating m and c in y = mx + c, however, the line will be used to ident the elements of the matrix, hence integers are needed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def maskImg(img, sensit=0.85):
    maxval = img.max()
    minval = sensit * maxval
    mask = (img >= minval) & (img <= maxval)
    return np.where(mask, 1, 0)

img_path = r"..."
img = mpimg.imread(img_path)[400:1000, 150:750].mean(axis=2)
img1 = maskImg(img)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img1)

sum_points = []

for x2 in range(0, 60):
    for x1 in range(540, 600):
        for y1 in range(0, 60):
            for y2 in range(540, 600):
                x_coords = np.linspace(x1, x2, img1.shape[0], dtype=int)
                y_coords = np.linspace(y1, y2, img1.shape[1], dtype=int)
                
                # Extract pixel values along the diagonal using array indexing
                pixel_values_on_line = img1[x_coords, y_coords]
                
                sum_points.append([(x_coords, y_coords), pixel_values_on_line.sum()])

max_coords, max_sum = max(sum_points, key=lambda x: x[1])

x, y = max_coords

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: How about using a computer vision library?

Comment: Do you have a specific function in mind? Did not thing that a function like this would exist, The problem is that I want to detect the angle of the line.

Comment: this package maybe helpfull https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Comment: You might be interested by the [Hough transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html)

Comment: I just tested the Hough transform out, and it did fit perfectly on the object thank you very much for recommending it!

Comment: @saha,  the python documentation in that module is missing indentation.... FYI. (i'm sure you spotted that).